# In Dapper, what does the Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map method parameter looks like. Is there a test case that I can look at?

Tags: c#, delegates, dapper

I have been trying to implement the below dapper method call. I do not know what is the expectation for the method parameter:

```
Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map
```

for this Dapper call:

```
Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>(string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, string splitOn = "Id", int? commandTimeout = default(int?), CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
```

Is there a test case that I can take a look at? I have not found one yet.

Comment: a function that receives 2 parameters, one of type `TFirst` and other of type `TSecond`, and returns an object of type `TReturn`

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand in little detail from the signature provided. Firstly this looks like an overload, otherwise the QueryAsync works in same way as Query, just that its Asynchronous. This would have made more sense for `QueryMultiple`

Important parts are:

`QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>` - Signature

`Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map` - Usage of Signature

Usage of Signature

`Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>>` - Return Type

Now since you are executing the `Query`, not `QueryMultiple`, so the return of the Sql Execution would be only single type, I assume `TReturn`, what Func delegate would do is, do some processing of the result, which you need to do by supplying the logic, something like, where TFirst and TSecond become integer types, it could be any type of your choice:

```
Func<int,int,TReturn> func = (a,b) => { use a,b values to filter the values in IEnumerable<Treturn> fetched and return the same }
```

I must admit that I am little confused though, since for doing anything inside the `QueryAsync` function means unwrapping the `Task`, which is returned from the Async function. Better solution here shall be:

Run QueryAsync as is:

```
Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TReturn>(string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, string splitOn = "Id", int? commandTimeout = default(int?), CommandType? commandType = default(CommandType?))
```

`var result = connection.QueryAsync<TReturn>(sql).Result;` // Making this as a blocking call just for example

Now apply the `Func` to transform the values inside `IEnumerable<TReturn>`